# Calculating average value per document with sort

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongoose model defined as such:

```
freelancerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 _id: { type: String, default: shortid.generate},
 fname: String,
 lname: String;
 ratings: [{
       rating: Number,
       employer: {
          type: String,
          ref: 'Employer'
           }
        }],
 ...
}]
```

This schema represents a mongoose model for a Freelancer collection. My question is: in a certain query I need to find all freelancers with all their data and calculate the average rating for each of them. In the end, I would get an array of freelancers, each having their own calculated average rating preferably stored in a new field "avg_rating" or something like that.

I've tried looking into the mongodb Aggregate but I honestly didn't understand much.

Thanks in advance and sorry if my explanation wasn't precise enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the average of fields in embedded documents/array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289071/calculate-the-average-of-fields-in-embedded-documents-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are going to play [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) here, then the expression can be shortened:

```
Freelancer.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "rating_avg": {
       "$reduce": {
        "input": "$ratings",
        "initialValue": 0,
        "in": {
          "$add": [ 
            "$$value",
            { "$divide": [ "$$this.rating", { "$size": "$ratings" } ] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "rating_avg": -1 } }
],function(err, results) {
  res.send(results)
})
```

Or even a bit shorter using [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) and [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/):

```
Freelancer.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "rating_avg": {
      "$avg": {
        "$map": { 
          "input": "$ratings",
          "as": "el",
          "in": "$$el.rating"
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "rating_avg": -1 } }
],function(err, results) {
  res.send(results)
})
```

And of course the shortest yet, being allowed since MongoDB 3.2 (modifying with `$project` of course):

```
Freelancer.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "rating_avg": { "$avg": "$ratings.rating" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "rating_avg": -1 } }
],function(err, results) {
  res.send(results)
})
```

All also using [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) as an alternate to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) when using MongoDB 3.4, which is where [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) becomes available. The second form when modified with [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) also becomes valid for MongoDB 3.2, as is also true ( and noted ) of the third.

Comment: Thanks again. Will try to implement these to get a better grasp on the aggregate operators later.

Comment: @KyleSentient Learning is fine, and fun :) I think the lesson here is that when you want an :"average" think `$avg`, and that common actions already have built in operators. `$reduce` is all fine "When you need it". But you don't really need it to perform common actions that there are already operators for. Here two things where introduced in MongoDB 3.2 1.) `$avg` accepts an array 2. The ability to "short notate" array expressions, such as a single property of an array like `$ratings.rating` into an array of just those values.

Answer (score 1):

After messing around with my code and reading some other stacks, I found a solution that works fine for my needs:

```
   Freelancer.aggregate(
    [{
            $project: {
                fname: "$fname",
                lname: "$lname",
                rating_avg: {
                    $divide: [{
                        $reduce: {
                            input: "$ratings.rating",
                            initialValue: 0,
                            in: {
                                $sum: ["$$value", "$$this"]
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        $size: "$ratings"
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                rating_avg: -1
            }
        }
    ],
    function (err, results) {
        res.send(results);
    });
});
```

Hope this can help somebody else in the future.

Comment: Important to note that since this does not require "aggregating" via a `$group` and is simply a calculation on the "present document" then this would be the optimal approach. I will note that the syntax can actually be a bit shorter using [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) since `$avg` like `$sum` in this listing can take an array as input.

Comment: Also since `$reduce` is being used ( a MongoDB 3.4 feature ) you can also [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) ( another MongoDB 3.4 ) instead of using `$project`, and avoid specifying "$fname" and "$lname". Which could also have just been written as `1` here.

Comment: @NeilLunn I see. I'm still a newbie when it comes to aggregation. Thanks a lot for the info. I'll try to optimize my code when I get the time